# Execution Timed Out (12000 ms): How can I optimize this code

Tags: c#, performance, optimization, c#-10.0

My task on codewars was to return true or false depending if the input number is [narcissistic number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Narcissistic_number) (e.g. 153 = 1^3 + 5^3 + 3^3). But when I tested my code it said that Execution Timed Out (12000 ms) and that I should optimize the code further.

Does anyone know how can i optimize the code below? The code below is written in C#.

```
public class Kata
{
  public static bool Narcissistic(int value)
  {
    int digit = 0;
    int tempValue=value;
    int checkValue=value;
    int num;
    double sum = 0;

    //number of digits
    while(value!=0){
      value = value%10;
      digit++;
      value=value/10;
    }
    
    //sum
    while(tempValue!=0){
      num=tempValue%10;
      sum=sum+pow(num,digit);
      num=num/10;
    }
    if(sum==checkValue){
      return true;
    }else 
      return false;
  }
  
  //power
  private static int pow(int a,int b){
    int temp = a;
    for(int i=1;i<b;i++){
      a=a*temp;
    }
    return a;
  }
}
```

Comment: Hint: have you debugged through the code? I suspect that your second `while` loop condition isn't what you intended. I'd also suggest you replace the final `if` block with just `return sum == check;`, follow .NET naming conventions (`Pow` not `pow` - or `Power` even) and use Visual Studio default formatting for both bracing and to avoid the code looking so cramped due to lack of whitespace.

Comment: `tempValue` will never be 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code `tempValue` was condition in loop but you never change the value so it's an infinity loop, not about performance

Maybe you can replace

```cs
while(tempValue!=0) {
    num=tempValue%10;
    sum=sum+pow(num,digit);
    num=num/10;
}
```

##### to

```cs
tempValue = -1;
while (tempValue != 0)
{
        int num = tempValue % 10;
        sum += Math.Pow(num, digit);
        tempValue /= 10;
}
```

#### Test case

```
Kata.Narcissistic(153);
// true

// DEBUG / NET6 [If you have care about performance]
// Time elapsed (ms): 6,998
// Time elapsed (ns): 7046900
```

Comment: Did I do something wrong It is returning `False`, see: https://onlinegdb.com/aPAEJWH-Q

Comment: I may have made some small changes in some places, I present the full code so you can compare it with mine. see: https://onlinegdb.com/v00Wof6kF

Comment: OK, I am not going to compare it, because I do not have enough time (now) to understand the problem (of this question).... 